# MySQL left join doesnt give me what i expect

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'd like some help with an left join statement thats not doing what i, probably incorrectly, think it should do.

there are two tables:

cd:

```
CREATE TABLE `cd` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `artist` text NOT NULL,
  `genre` text NOT NULL,
  `tracks` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`)
)
```

loans

```
CREATE TABLE `loans` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dueDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`,`itemType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and i want to select all cd's thats not in loans using a left join and then an where dueDate is null

```
select 
    t.itemID, 
    t.artist as first, 
    t. title as second, 
    (select AVG(rating) from ac9039.ratings where itemType = 'cd' and itemId = t.itemID) as `rating avarage`, 
    (select COUNT(rating) from ac9039.ratings where itemType = 'cd' and itemId = t.itemID) as `number of ratings` 
from 
    cd t left join loans l 
    on t.itemID = l.itemID 
where l.itemType = 'cd' and l.dueDate is null;
```

this one however returns an empty table even though there are plenty rows in cd with itemIDs thats not in loans

now i was under the understanding that the left join should preserv the righthandside and fill the columns from the lefthandside with null values
but this does not seem to be the case, can anbyone enlighten me?

Comment: change 'where' to 'and' and change 'and' to 'where'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition causes the error. The `L.ItemType = 'cd'` will always return false if the `L.DueDate IS NULL` is true. (All of your fields are `NOT NULL`, so the `DueDate` can only be `NULL` if there is no matching records, but in this case the `ItemType` field will be `NULL` too).

Another point is that your query is semantically incorrect. You are trying to get the record from the `cd` table where the `loans` table do not contains any rows with dueDates.
The second table acts as a condition, so it should go to the `WHERE` conditions.

Consider to use the `EXISTS` statement to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT 
    t.itemID, 
    t.artist as first, 
    t. title as second, 
    (select AVG(rating) from ac9039.ratings where itemType = 'cd' and itemId = t.itemID) as `rating avarage`, 
    (select COUNT(rating) from ac9039.ratings where itemType = 'cd' and itemId = t.itemID) as `number of ratings` 
FROM 
    cd t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM loans l WHERE t.itemID = l.itemID AND L.itemType = 'cd')
```

Based on your data model you have to add another condition to the subquery to filter out those records which are out-of-date now (dueDate is earlier than the current time)

This is the case, when you do not delete outdated loan records.

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM loans l WHERE t.itemID = l.itemID AND AND L.itemType = 'cd' l.dueDate > NOW())
```

Comment: Is this helpful? I'm not convinced.

Comment: The query in the question is semantically incorrect, this is why I suggested the EXISTS aproach. OK, and now I see what do you mean :)

Comment: @Strawberry I've just updated my answere to be a bit more precise.